# I don't know why the errors expected aand expected while keep appearing ,and I also don't know what's wrong

Tags: c, numbers

[image]
I don't know why the errors expected aand expected while keep appearing ,and I also don't know what's wrong.

#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

```
int n, copie, oglindit=0, cifra;
scanf("%d",&n);
copie=n;
do while(n!=0){
      cifra= n%10;
      oglindit= oglindit*10+ cifra;
      n= n%10;
    }
if(copie==oglindit) printf("Numarul e palindrom\n");
  else printf("Numarul nu e palindrom\n");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Remove the `do` before `while`

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as image and indicate the programming language used (as tag).

Comment: the programming language is C, done

Comment: `do { /*loop body goes here*/} while(/*loop condition here*/) `

Answer (score 1):

For var `n`: replace second modulo `% 10` with divide `/ 10`, example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, copie, oglindit = 0, cifra;

    printf("numar: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "scan error\n");
        return (1);
    }

    for (copie = n; n != 0; n /= 10) {
        cifra = n % 10;
        oglindit = (oglindit * 10) + cifra;
    }

    printf("Numarul %se palindrom\n", (copie == oglindit) ? "" : "nu ");
    return 0;
}
```